# Node.js SQL Server code seems to be wrong, but still works?

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, postgresql, heroku

Trying to pick an entry by attribute (id, user_name, foo, bar, whatever);

Here's my socketing code;

```js
socket.on('database attribute', function(msg) {
  queryDriver.getAllEntriesByAttribute(gatheringstable, 'user_name', 'john', function(err, gatherings) {
   console.log(gatherings);
   io.emit('database attribute', gatherings);
  });
 });
```

Here's my database driver code;

```js
QueryDriver.prototype.getAllEntriesByAttribute = function(table, attribute, value, callback) {
 this.dbclient.query('SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' WHERE ' + attribute + '=' + value, function(err, result) {
  if(err) {
   callback(err);
  }
  else {
   callback(null, result.rows);
  }
 });
};
```

If we take a look at a typical statement for this SQL command, it looks like `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE attribute='value';"`. This will pull an entry with the 'user_name' attribute of 'john' out of the database.

This works in my `'heroku pg:psql' daemon.`

This does not work in my code for some reason, UNLESS I change the position of 'value' and 'attribute' in the command. Like this;

```js
socket.on('database attribute', function(msg) {
  queryDriver.getAllEntriesByAttribute(gatheringstable, 'john', 'user_name', function(err, gatherings) {
   console.log(gatherings);
   io.emit('database attribute', gatherings);
  });
 });
```

Then it will work just fine for my heroku implementation, I can call it and get `[{"id":1,"user_name":"john"}]` but it refuses to work in my 'heroku pg:psql' daemon.

Have I discovered the worlds most benign SQL fault?

Is reality falling apart?

Why does this work in reverse? `"user_name"="john"` is the ACTUAL way you would call it, but `"john"="user_name"` is the only CORRECT way that works for me.

Comment: btw, console.log(err); would help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following.

Inside of the daemon I tested two commands;

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE 'user_name' = 'john'
```

Which returned "null"

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE user_name = 'john'
```

Which returned "1 column"

And while Vao Tsun's answer is close, it does not actually fix this particular problem, but it gave me a neat hint as to what to do.

The correct implementation is this;

```
QueryDriver.prototype.getAllEntriesByAttribute = function(table, attribute, value, callback) {
    this.dbclient.query('SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' WHERE ' + attribute + '=' + "'" + value + "'", function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
        }
        else {
            callback(null, result.rows);
        }
    });
};
```

Which is equivalent to doing the second command,

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE user_name = 'john'
```

And so the **ATTRIBUTE must NOT** be surrounded by quotes, the **VALUE must be** surrounded by quotes.

Vao Tsun's answer is close, but only works when you are not referencing a text value. If you're looking for a column with a text value, you must not escape the attribute with quotes. You must escape the value.

And thus,

```
[{"id":1,"user_name":"john"}]
```

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
'SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' WHERE ' + attribute + '=' + value
```

to

```
'SELECT * FROM ' + table + ' WHERE "' + attribute + '"=' + value
```

in your driver code, should let you use "right" order I guess.

BTW for sql there is no difference if you check for true/false 1=2 or 2=1, so that "standart" order is really a human preference, not more

Comment: Wait what? I don't see what mean. There are no escape quotes (") in my query code.

Comment: I wrote it the opposite :) I meant you to try adding double quotes around column name

Comment: Ah, I will try this when I am home, will let you know.

Comment: Aw, for some reason that still doesn't work. Any thoughts?